# Changing a background image of <body> (in CSS) depending on the season (Current Calendar Month)

Tags: javascript, html, css, comparison-operators

I'd like to change my HTML background depending on the date, but what I've written isn't working properly. I can't find any applicable examples and I'm struggling to complete it.

I just want the start of a new season to change the background of my HTML page by altering the image used in my CSS file.

**JavaScript:**

```
var d = new Date();
var Day = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
if (Month == <3 && Month == 5) {
    document.background-image: url("springTree.jpg");
} else if (Month == < 6 && Month == > 8) {
    document.background-image: url("summerTree.jpg");
} else if (Month == < 9 && Month == > 11) {
    document.background-image: url("autumnTree.jpg");
} else (Month == 12 && Month == > 2) {
    document.background-image: url("winterTree.jpg");
```

**CSS:**

```
div.body {
  background-image: url("summertree.jpg");
    width: 640px;
    height: 1136px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm not sure if this could be accomplished with JQuery but I'm willing to experiment with anything.

As you can see I clearly have no clue what I'm doing and I'm in need of some help, thanks.

Comment: post the full javascript

Comment: in javascript, months are 0-11, not 1-12 - perhaps this causes your problems?

Comment: I would suggest a css class for each season and then you can just set the right class to the body. :-)

Comment: this: `if (Month == <3 && Month == 5) { ` looks weird to me... does that work? have you tried an `alert` in your conditions to see if anything fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use class injection into the `<html>` tag. Javascript code will inject whatever class you want (depending on location (winter vs summer) or local time (day vs night)). And your css will have the backgrounds (or any other differences accordingly.

CSS:

```
.spring {background-image: url("springTree.jpg");}
.summer {background-image: url("summerTree.jpg");}
...
```

You can also have other differences:

```
.spring li a {color: green}
.winter li a {color: white}
```

You can set the class from javascript like this:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
html.setAttribute('class', 'spring');
```

Or if you want multiple classes inject (add) the one you need:

```
root.classList.add('evening');
```

With your conditions:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
if (month >= 3 && month <= 5) {
    root.classList.add('spring');
} else if (month >= 6 && month <= 8) {
    root.classList.add('summer');
} else if (month >= 9 && month <= 11) {
    root.classList.add('autumn');
} else(month == 12 || month <= 2) {
    root.classList.add('winter');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "set inject the class from JavaScript"? Should that bit of code be contained in another JavaScript file that's called from my HTML? Also, do I just call my CSS file and Javascript file (using the code you've given) from my html file for this to work? Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @BOUYBOY, It doesn't matter wether you have your js, css inline inside your html or link it from other file. That part of the code adds a class to the <html> tag, so if you have your css with prefixes like `.spring` then from now on those css rules will act

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should take a look on how to compare in JS. This site has a good list of operators and what they do:

[JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

`if(Month == < 3)` should be `if(Month <= 3)`.

And read your conditions out loud:

```
if (Month <= 3 && Month == 5)
if (Month <= 6 && Month >= 8)
```

Can the month be lower or equal to 3 **and** equals 5? Can the month be lower or equal to 6 **and** higher or equal to 8? (No, probably not in this universe.)

As for swapping images, how does your html look? Do you have a div with a class called `body`? Or are you looking for the body tag? If you are looking for the body tag you can change the background image like this.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('springTree.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
var d = new Date();
var Day = d.getDate();
// Below function returs 0 to 11. So we have added +1
var Month = d.getMonth() + 1;

// January, February, December
if (Month == 12 || Month <= 2) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = url("winterTree.jpg");
}
// March, April, May 
else if (Month >= 3 && Month <= 5) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = url("springTree.jpg");
}
// June, July, August
else if (Month >= 6 && Month <= 8) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = url("summerTree.jpg");
}
// September, October, November
else if (Month >= 9 && Month <= 11) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = url("autumnTree.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised by your approach of writng JavaScript. It would be great if you can have a look on [JavaScript | MDN - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and check how to target classes and overwrite styles. Below is your solution.

```
var d = new Date();
var Day = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth(); 

if (Month <= 3 || Month === 5) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.background = "url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/my-cat-mimi_2568679.jpg')";
    console.log('1');
} else if (Month <= 6 || Month >= 8) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.background = "url('https: //image.freepik.com/free-photo/clouds-above-the-volcano_426-19322758.jpg')";
    console.log('2');
} else if (Month <= 9 || Month >= 11) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.background = "url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/my-cat-mimi_2568679.jpg')";
    console.log('3');
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.background = "url('https: //image.freepik.com/free-photo/clouds-above-the-volcano_426-19322758.jpg')";
    console.log('4');
}
```

instead of using && you should check || if you are trying to get image change between first month and fifth month. You should definitely have a look at:

[JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)!

Therefore you should not write `if(Month == < 3)` It should be `if(Month <= 3)`.

To change or target classes in HTML Dom, have a look here

[Javascript Class Targeting](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Ps: working Fiddle here [Change Pic depending using Dates](https://jsfiddle.net/yeoman/f74nhr95/)

Happy Learning. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var Day = d.getDate();
var Month = d.getMonth();
if (Month == <3 && Month == 5) {
    document.background-image: url("springTree.jpg");
} else if (Month == < 6 && Month == > 8) {
    document.background-image: url("summerTree.jpg");
} else if (Month == < 9 && Month == > 11) {
    document.background-image: url("autumnTree.jpg");
} else (Month == 12 && Month == > 2) {
    document.background-image: url("winterTree.jpg");
```

Please check all your conditions.
Example: Month==12 and Month<=2  :( month in year can't is 12 and <2
you should change (Month == 12 || Month == > 2)